# Convert Python nested Dict to Numpy array

Tags: python, json, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I have a dictionary in the format of:

```
{"k": {"k1": [[v1]],"k2": [[v2]],"k3": [[v3]]}
```

How do I convert it to two arrays in the below format:

```
[kk1,kk2,kk3]
[v1,v2,v3]
```

I have a function in Python, however I couldn't get the result in the required format.

```
def dict_to_list_of_keys(d, l, loc):
    for k in iter(d):
        loc.append(k)
        l.append(loc * 1)
        if isinstance(d[k], dict):
            dict_2_list_of_keys(d[k], l, loc)
        loc.pop()
    return l
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `for` loop with `list.append`. To convert a list to an array is trivial, i.e. `np.array(L)`.

```
d = {"k": {"k1": [['v1']],"k2": [['v2']],"k3": [['v3']]}}

keys, values = [], []

for k1, v1 in d.items():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        keys.append(k1+k2)
        values.append(v2[0][0])

print(keys, values, sep='\n')

['kk1', 'kk2', 'kk3']
['v1', 'v2', 'v3']
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use pandas for this. First create a dataframe from the dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict_test = {"k": {"k1": [['v1']],"k2": [['v2']],"k3": [['v3']]}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_test)
```

Pandas smartly makes the key values into an index and the actual list values as the data. Now you can subset the data frame to pull the data out any way you like. One suggestion is to create a new column out of the index like this:

```
df['key_value'] = df.index
```

Now you can reference the key values just like any other column. If you have a more complex dictionary pandas will create a column for each key/value pair which means you may have to melt the data frame to a more useful shape.

Finally if you then want to convert to a numpy array somewhere along the line, since each individual list is a cell in the data frame you should use something like apply (assuming df now is just a single column of lists)

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.array(x))
```

You will get back a numpy array for each row in the data frame. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

```
import numpy as np

d = {"k": {"k1": [['v1']],"k2": [['v2']],"k3": [['v3']]}}

lst = []
for k, v in d.items():
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        lst.extend([(k+k1, v1[0][0])])

print(np.array(list(zip(*lst))))
# [['kk1' 'kk2' 'kk3']
#  ['v1' 'v2' 'v3']]
```

Comment: When I try lst.extend([(k+k1, v1[0][0])]) I get IndexError: list index out of range however, when I try to use lst.extend([(k+k1, v1)]) it stores the value, yet doesn't convert to numpy array with the error message: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence